# How to deal with an IDisposable repository with Unity?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a job in which I have an IDisposable DbContext. I would like to unit test this job without hitting in a database. What options do i have to do this?

Im using the default Fakes assembly' of microsoft.

My job:

```
public void Work()
{
    do
    {   
        //code here                
        using (var repository = new Repository<User>())
        {
            repository.Save(user);
        }

    } while (true);
}
```

I'm trying to test and in this part of the test it fails because it actually creates a new instance of the Repository class.

My test Method:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    Data.Repository.Fakes.ShimRepository<Domain.Fakes.ShimUser>.Constructor = (a) => { };

    Data.Repository.Fakes.ShimRepository<Domain.Fakes.ShimUser>.AllInstances.SaveT0 = (a, b) =>
    {
    };

   var service = GetService();
    service.Work(); //Throws exception
}
```

How can I fake this `Save` method?

Comment: see Dependency Injection - you need to allow a passed in parameter to Work()  Or at least into service otherwise it always create a real one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fakes, but perhaps it's just not fully-featured enough for your needs. I know this is trivial with a library like Moq (https://github.com/Moq/moq4).

Comment: It wouldn't be trivial with Moq either, since he is instantiating an actual concrete instance of the repository in the Work.

Comment: Using MS Fakes, or TypeMock etc, should be a last resort. Abstract your code into interfaces if you can, unless it really is code you can't control, which in that case you should use a fakes type of framework.

Comment: Yes I understand that its a violation of DIP, but the problem is that i must dispose this context every loop.

Answer (score 7):

You've violated [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) here, making unit testing your service far more difficult than it should be. You should also avoid generic repositories and favour [role interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html).

Instead, inject an abstraction into your service of your repository, e.g. `IUsersRepository` which defines your `Save` method. Then in your unit test of the service you can simply use a stub implementation of `IUsersRepository`.

Comment: Yes, but how about the dispose of the object? If i inject it once, the job will run forever with the first instance of the context.

Comment: Disposing is an implementation detail of the Entity Framework implementation of the abstraction. Therefore the disposing is done within e.g. EntityFrameworkUsersRepository.

Answer (score 2):

Fakes tend to reveal that your code is not properly following the D in SOLID since you are creating dependencies inside your class instead of passing them in.

A much better pattern would to create an `ISaveRepository` interface that in turn implements IDisposable with an exposed `Save()` method.  You should then inject an instance of your repository into your class.  This will allow you to satisfy the using statement testing, as well as implement a mock that defines a `.Save()` method that does not hit the database.

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly ISaveRepository _userRepository;

    public Test(ISaveRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public void Work()
    {
        using (_userRepository)
        {
            var cont = true;
            do
            {              
                _userRepository.Save(new User());
                cont = false;
            } while (cont);
        } 
    }
}

public interface ISaveRepository : IDisposable
{
    void Save<T>(T model);
}

public class Repository<T> : ISaveRepository
{
    public void Dispose() { }
    public void Save<TT>(TT model) {}
}

public class User {}
```

Comment: Will your stub implementation need a dispose? Will an XML repository need a dispose? Will a web service call repository need a dispose? etc etc.

Comment: @ggui I'm assuming then that you were originally re-creating the connection to avoid holding a connection for an extended period of time?